# Highlighting JSON solr response using Jquery

Tags: jquery

Can you please suggest me how do I parse the JSON response to highlight only harsha in the given response.I want to highlight this only in the table data for name where only harsha is highlighted.Please suggest.

```
{
    "_header": {
        "nvPairs": [
            "status",
            0,
            "QTime",
            3,
            "params",
            {
                "nvPairs": [
                    "hl.fragsize",
                    "100000",
                    "hl.simple.pre",
                    "<em>",
                    "hl.fl",
                    "name",
                    "wt",
                    "javabin",
                    "hl.maxAnalyzedChars",
                    "100000",
                    "hl",
                    "true",
                    "version",
                    "2",
                    "hl.highlightMultiTerm",
                    "true",
                    "hl.snippets",
                    "100",
                    "hl.useFastVectorHighlighter",
                    "true",
                    "q",
                    "harsha",
                    "hl.regex.slop",
                    "0.5",
                    "hl.regex.pattern",
                    "[-\\w ,/\n\\\"']*",
                    "hl.simple.post",
                    "</em>"
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    "_results": [
        {
            "id": "21",
            "name": [
                "asd asda fsdfsdfds harsha sadaks asdasd sad fsddsf dsfdsf dsf sdf dsdsf sdfdsf dsfdsf dsf fdsdfsd fdsfdsf dfdsfdsfds  dsfsdf d f ds fdf df df dsfdsf dfdsf d      fdsdf dfs harsha"
            ],
            "_version_": 1508203924863058000
        }
    ],
    "_highlightingInfo": {
        "nvPairs": [
            "21",
            {
                "nvPairs": [
                    "name",
                    [
                        "asd asda fsdfsdfds <em>harsha</em> sadaks asdasd sad fsddsf dsfdsf dsf sdf dsdsf sdfdsf dsfdsf dsf fdsdfsd fdsfdsf dfdsfdsfds  dsfsdf d f ds fdf df df dsfdsf dfdsf d      fdsdf dfs <em>harsha</em>"
                    ]
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    "_highlighting": {
        "21": {
            "name": [
                "asd asda fsdfsdfds <em>harsha</em> sadaks asdasd sad fsddsf dsfdsf dsf sdf dsdsf sdfdsf dsfdsf dsf fdsdfsd fdsfdsf dfdsfdsfds  dsfsdf d f ds fdf df df dsfdsf dfdsf d      fdsdf dfs <em>harsha</em>"
            ]
        }
    },
    "elapsedTime": 19,
    "response": {
        "nvPairs": [
            "responseHeader",
            {
                "nvPairs": [
                    "status",
                    0,
                    "QTime",
                    3,
                    "params",
                    {
                        "nvPairs": [
                            "hl.fragsize",
                            "100000",
                            "hl.simple.pre",
                            "<em>",
                            "hl.fl",
                            "name",
                            "wt",
                            "javabin",
                            "hl.maxAnalyzedChars",
                            "100000",
                            "hl",
                            "true",
                            "version",
                            "2",
                            "hl.highlightMultiTerm",
                            "true",
                            "hl.snippets",
                            "100",
                            "hl.useFastVectorHighlighter",
                            "true",
                            "q",
                            "harsha",
                            "hl.regex.slop",
                            "0.5",
                            "hl.regex.pattern",
                            "[-\\w ,/\n\\\"']*",
                            "hl.simple.post",
                            "</em>"
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            "response",
            [
                {
                    "id": "21",
                    "name": [
                        "asd asda fsdfsdfds harsha sadaks asdasd sad fsddsf dsfdsf dsf sdf dsdsf sdfdsf dsfdsf dsf fdsdfsd fdsfdsf dfdsfdsfds  dsfsdf d f ds fdf df df dsfdsf dfdsf d      fdsdf dfs harsha"
                    ],
                    "_version_": 1508203924863058000
                }
            ],
            "highlighting",
            {
                "nvPairs": [
                    "21",
                    {
                        "nvPairs": [
                            "name",
                            [
                                "asd asda fsdfsdfds <em>harsha</em> sadaks asdasd sad fsddsf dsfdsf dsf sdf dsdsf sdfdsf dsfdsf dsf fdsdfsd fdsfdsf dfdsfdsfds  dsfsdf d f ds fdf df df dsfdsf dfdsf d      fdsdf dfs <em>harsha</em>"
                            ]
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I implemented the Solr Search highlighting using following jquery code.Hope it helps someone.

```
var highlight = {};

    $.each(newresult._highlighting, function(i, hitem){
        var match = hitem.name[0].match(/<em>(.*?)<\/em>/);
      // var match = hitem.description[0].match(/elegant/g);
        console.log("match "+match);
        highlight[i] = match[1];


    });
    var res1 = newresult._highlighting;
    var results;
    var result;
    for(var res2 in res1)
    {
        var hlight = res1[res2].name;
        results= highlight[res2];

    }

    $.each(hlight, function(ix, items){
        var word = results;
        result = items.replace(new RegExp(word, 'g'),word);

    });
 $("body").append('<div>' + result + '</div>');
```